# Запустить main.java из index.jsp

Tags: java, веб-программирование, intellij-idea, main

Пытаюсь перевести код java в web.

Как запустить класс main.java из index.jsp?

Answer (score 2):

```
<body>
<%
  MyClass mc = new MyClass();
  mc.test();
%>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<jsp:useBean id="main" class="main" scope="request" />

<body>
    //используйте бин здесь...  
</body>
```